# Collating cron output for periodic e-mails

Tags: email, cron, logwatch

`vixie-cron` e-mails me the output of cron jobs, with one message per job.

I would rather receive messages in batches, with either a configurable number of messages per batch or (better) each batch covering a defined time period. I already use [logwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logwatch) to get daily e-mails; a solution that could be integrated  into this system would be ideal.

I can't find a way of configuring `vixie-cron` (version `4.1-81`) to output to a directory or a log file instead of directly to the SMTP client. I am aware that I can manually redirect the output to a different location in `crontab` itself, but it seems like there should be a way to change the default.

I also wonder what the best tool for sending the e-mails would be (if not logwatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Cron to send the output to syslog. I believe that cron output will be sent to /var/log/cron on most systems. From here, you can create a logwatch job to scan /var/log/cron and send you the output once per day.

From [man 8 cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron):

> -s
>
> This option will direct cron to send job output to the system log
>   using syslog(3). This is useful if your system has no sendmail(8), or
>   if mail is disabled using -m off.

On some distros, logwatch comes with a logwatch script named 'cron' and a configuration file named 'cron.conf'. See http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/logwatch/files/ for one example. I do not have these files on my RHEL6 system.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Not sure how I missed the `-s` option in the man page.

Answer (score 0):

What about settine the email address for a specific cron (MAILTO=mailname, if I recall) where all the mail messages go and have an alias to simply put it into a file.  Then process the file as you wish, .... logrotate, or whatever else you want.